# Can JDK crypto make use of a Microsoft Windows Cryprographic Service Provider?

Tags: java, cryptography, code-signing

As far as I can tell (I'm very new to this) this would require JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) to be set up to talk to the Windows CSP. Is this possible?

Obviously, this would be utterly Windows-specific. That's OK for the use case, which would be doing code signing, using a customised WCSP, which ends up producing standard signatures.

The issue is not about code, but signing the code. It's desirable to be able to use the customised WCSP for doing the cryptography for code signing. It will be created for use with other kinds of code signing, but being able to use it for Java code signing (with jarsigner) would be convenient. So this is an "unusual requirement."

Comment: Why does it matter? Your code is written to the JCA api. The way crypto providers actually implement it should be of no concern unless you have some unusual requirements.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: Added more explanation.

Comment: You can treat the Windows provider as a PKCS#11 provider. Details are in the JCE Guide.

Comment: @user207421: Would you like to make that into an answer, perhaps with a bit more detail?

Comment: @user207421 PKCS#11 is only an interface, however what is still missing is a PKCS#11 module that accesses the Windows CSP. AFAIK there are no free PKCS#11 providers available that would do so (if I am wrong please provide a link to such a PKCS#11 module).